# Does Bernie Sanders have more individual donors than any candidate in history?

Tags: united-states, politics, bernie-sanders

This [NPR / article](http://www.politicususa.com/2015/11/05/bernie-sanders-donors-point-candidate-history.html) has the headline

> "Bernie Sanders Now Has More Donors At This Point Than Any Other Candidate In History"

I am skeptical that this is true especially in the latter part of the Obama '08 campaign.

Is there any authoritative information that can assert this to be true (or false), ... or put it into some kind of perspective?

Comment: A bit of a clarification. The article says more precisely: "We have received more individual contributions, 750,000, than any candidate in American history **at this point in the campaign**."

Comment: If my impression that US election campaigns get longer and longer is true, then 750,000 individuals more than a year before election date may be quite true.

Comment: Keep in mind our population is continually growing.  According to these numbers there are now 16 million more people in the US than there were in 2008 when Obama was running the first time.  (http://www.multpl.com/united-states-population/table) Records based on total number of people doing something are probably broken a lot when a population is always growing.